# Piping file contents to ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, cat, piping

I'm currently using this ffmpeg command to generate 2 png images from the raw image fb0 file on an android device.

> ffmpeg -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb32 -s 720x1280 -i fb0
>   -f image2 -vcodec png image_%03d.png

I'm pulling the fb0 file with adb pull before running this command but I'm wondering if I can just cat and pipe the output of it to the ffmpeg command rather than having to save the file locally beforehand. Is this possible, and if so how would it be done? Thanks

edit: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567067/2739431) post from 2010 says piping in ffmpeg can only be done with video, is this still the case?

I tried to do this, and it does work except my image is distorted, any suggestions?

> adb shell cat /dev/graphics/fb0 | ffmpeg -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo
>   -pix_fmt rgb32 -s 720x1280 -i pipe:0 -f image2 -vcodec png image_%03d.png

it gives an "Invalid buffer size" error too.