# ffmpeg does not fill in my provided buffer

Tags: go, ffmpeg

I'm trying to pipe a mp4 video to ffmpeg to generate a thumbnail. Unfortunately, ffmpeg does not fill in my provided buffer, even though the whole command execution is successful.

I'm reading the video from a http request body:

```
videoData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
```

This is how I push it to ffmpeg:

```
log.Print("Creating thumbnail..")

width := 640
height := 360
log.Print("Size of the video: ", len(videoData))


cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-i", "pipe:0", "-vframes", "1", "-s", fmt.Sprintf("%dx%d", width, height), "-f",  "singlejpeg", "-frame_size", fmt.Sprintf("%d", totalVideoBytes), "-")

cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(videoData)

var imageBuffer bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &imageBuffer
err := cmd.Run()

if err != nil {
    log.Panic("ERROR")
}

imageBytes := imageBuffer.Bytes()
```

This is the error output:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7ff05d002600]stream 0, offset 0x5ded: partial file
>
> pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
>
> Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
>
> frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0
> Lsize=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
> video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB
> muxing overhead: unknown
>
> Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

Thanks a lot, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Inspect ffmpeg's error output with `cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr`, for instance.

Comment: @Peter Hello peter, I have added the log to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Add `"-"` as the last argument in your command.

Comment: @TimCooper Hello tim, I updated the command and the error logs. Thanks.

Comment: `pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input` sounds like the contents of `videoData` is invalid. Where is this coming from?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That's where it gets weird. I researched on the internet and all indications pointed on an invalid file. However, I've tried it with various valid files, and none of them worked.

Comment: Maybe you have an error in how you're reading the files from disk, or something like that? It would be helpful if you could create a complete example ([mcve]). It's possible that the error in your code (if any) is in the code you *didn't* post here.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Hello Carpetsmoker! Thanks a lot for taking your valuable time to help me. I'm reading the video from a http request body and added the code snipped to my original question. Have a good evening!

Comment: are you sure that r.Body is properly encoded/decoded? Please, do the following to confirm: 1. save body to a regular video file (avi, mp4, etc.) 2. try to play this file in a video player, if it's ok
3. exec your ffmpeg command with this file (instead of pipe) in terminal and check the result

Comment: @vitr Hello, Yes I think it's properly encoded. I was able to play and analyse the file after I uploaded it to S3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4585976/4986182